# How many labelled directed trees with given bi-degree sequence are there?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I consider *directed trees* on $[n]$, i.e. digraphs with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ whose underlying graph is a tree.  The *bidegree sequence* of a directed tree is the sequence $\left( (w_i, l_i) : i \in [n] \right)$, where $w_i$ (resp. $l_i$) is the outdegree (resp. indegree) of the vertex $i$.

It is known that given a sequence $s =(w_i, l_i)$, there is a directed tree on $[n]$ with degree sequence $s$ iff $\sum w_i = \sum l_i = n-1$ and for all $i$, $w_i + l_i \ge 1$.  My question is:

Given such a sequence $s$ how many directed trees are there having degree sequence $s$?

In page 14 of [*Counting Labelled Trees*](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/hidden/papers/Moon-counting_labelled_trees.pdf), J. W. Moon gives the formula

$$ \binom{n-2}{w_1+l_1-1,\ldots,w_n+l_n-1}$$

but this clearly overcounts.  For example if we take the sequence $\left((1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (0,2)\right)$ the formula gives $2$ but there is only one directed tree realizing this sequence:

```
         2      1    
         o     o     
        / \   /      
       /   \ /       
      o     o        
      3     4
```

Comment: It is suspicious that the formula is identical to that given on the previous page for the number of underlying undirected trees.

Comment: @Ben: Right!  That's what made me suspicious originally.  Thanks for the edit BTW